# Finding type of column/attribute in Rails generator template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ruby-on-rails-5, code-generation

Is there a way to find out what type (either database or Ruby) a column/attribute is from within a generator template such as for the view or _form? I can get a little info from `attribute.field_type`, but it seems to be what kind of HTML input Rails thinks it should use for that, so it's indirect. Both string and references (a foreign key) result in text_field, boolean gives check_box, etc.

If there is a way to do this I'd really like to see where the documentation is, as I've had no luck finding it. The [Rails Guide section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates) doesn't give much info, and as far as I can tell the [Thor](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/erikhuda/thor/master/Thor/Actions.html) docs don't have what I want; I'm specifically looking for info (including what they do, not just a list) on what methods can be called on the class that's being generated and its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the below mentioned line:

I'm specifically looking for info on what methods can be called on the class that's being generated and its attributes.

There is function called "methods" which can called on class as well as instance of an class which will give the list of available methods on that paticular class (or instance).

Say there is a class named User, then all methods for that particular class can be found using the below mentioned command:

```
User.methods
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really hoping to find the actual documentation here. Not just a list of the functions but description of what they do as well. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the specific in detail docs (not just the rails guides):
http://api.rubyonrails.org/

You can go in-depth on pretty much everything. For example you can go into ActiveRecord:AttributeMethods and poke around in there. I am not exactly certain what you are looking for but I believe you will find it near there.